# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" When adding new WCF Service

Tags: web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2019

When trying to add a new WCF Service to an existing project in Visual Studio 2019, I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", and the svc files does not get added to the project.  For example, if the file I try to add is "Service.svc", the file "IService.cs" will be added, but not "Service.svc".  Has anyone encountered something like this and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

By adding service will generate a client proxy containing the service interface, instead of a service implemented class. afterward, we could call the WCF service by means of a client proxy as like calling a local method.

```
  ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            var result = client.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The Url in the Adding Service Reference dialog is the service metadata address.

> http://vabqia969vm:8818/Service1.svc

Alternatively, it could be the Mex endpoint when the WCF service is self-hosted.

> https://vabqia969vm:21011/mex

Please refer to the below official documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.